# mongodb don't know what to do with subdirectory "dump/admin"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, nodebb

I am using nodebb on openshift. My mongodb version is `2.4.9` on openshift. I mongodumped and downloaded the dump folder to my e:\mongodump\ and extracted to folder named dump. It contain two subdirectories named "admin" and "nodebb". My local mongodb version is 3.0.6. I tried running mongorestore -d nodebb dump
But its ending with error `dont know what to do with subdirectory dump/admin, dont know what to do with subdirectory dump/nodebb`. Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I had to enter into the dump folder and manually run mongorestore for the two folders `nodebb` and `admin`.